# Parse push notification with iOS

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I tried to send notification to user.
Heres my code

```
PFQuery *qry = [PFUser query];
[qry getObjectWithId:user.objectId];

PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:qry];

// Send push notification to query
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:pushQuery]; // Set our Installation query
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"A New Push Message was Put HERE!", @"alert",
                      @"ursound.caf", @"sound",
                      @"Increment", @"badge",
                      @"Optionally a type was set", @"type",
                      nil];
[push setData:data];


[push sendPushInBackground];
```

But, when I send it, there is no effect. On Parse push notification panel displayed

Pushes Sent 0

When I send(as test) by "send a push" button, it's ok.

Any help?

Comment: If you run your `pushQuery` independently, do you get the expected `Installation` object returned?

Comment: Thanks of reply!
To remove "A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug."
 I modified the code with meted 
getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)

 And you are right
 PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query]; return pushQuery = null. 

Why is it so?
 getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block: return right object(user) 

Regards!

Comment: Do you have a `Pointer` field called `user` on your `Installation` class that contains the user you're trying to send your push to?